# How to merge several audio tracks into one track (for an iPod)?

Tags: audio, ipod

I don't have the original CD anymore and I don't want to see all the tracks, it was a speech and it created a track every minute - so the hour has 60 tracks (and I did this for about 100 CDs) so my question is - is there any program that I can throw all 60 tracks in one shot and it merges it into one long track?

Comment: We *don't* e mail answers here - the point of the QA format is that it helps future users as well. Answers cross pollinate, get selected for fitness, and that will help get better answers. As such, i've taken the liberty of deleting your e mail address. Feel free to come back and select the answer you felt was most useful, and learn, and contribute to the SU community ;)

Answer (score 1):

I favour [fre:ac](http://www.bonkenc.org/) for this - drag all the files into a window, select encode to one file option, and thats pretty much it

[image]